# Equality singular value $\sigma_1(A)=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert=1}\lVert Ax\rVert=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert =1,\lVert y\rVert=1}\langle Ax,y\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, singular-values

I am trying to solve:
$\sigma_1(A) = \sup\limits_{\lVert x \rVert = 1} \ \lVert A x \rVert = \sup\limits_{\lVert x \rVert = 1, \lVert y \rVert = 1} \langle Ax,y\rangle$
where $\sigma_1(A)$ is the largest singular value of $A$, $A$ being an $n \times p$ matrix.

The first equality is thanks to the decomposition $A = U \Sigma V^T$, with $U$ and $V$ being unitary, but I am not sure about the second one.

Thank you

Comment: Take $y=\frac {Ax}{\|Ax\|}$

Comment: This would yield $<Ax, y> = \frac{1}{\lVert Ax \rVert} x^T V \Sigma U^T U \Sigma V^T x = \frac{1}{\lVert Ax \rVert} x^T V \Sigma^2 V^T x = \frac{1}{\lVert Ax \rVert} (\Sigma V^T x)^2$

Comment: Do not bring in $A=U\Sigma V^{T}$.

Comment: So I would have $<Ax, y> = \frac{1}{\lVert Ax \rVert} x^T A^T A x = \frac{1}{\lVert Ax \rVert} x^T(A^T Ax)$
So it would be $\sup\limits_{\lVert x \rVert = 1} \frac{1}{\lVert Ax \rVert} x^T (A^T A x)$ and I missing something... this probably has something to do with the $A^T A$.

Comment: Hint: what is $\|Ax\|^2$ ? Use that and geetha's hint to prove $\|A\|\leq \sup_{\|x\|=\|y\|=1}\langle Ax, y\rangle$ Then prove the opposite direction using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: I see, thank you! this is $\frac{1}{\lVert Ax \rVert} \lVert A x \rVert^2 = \lVert Ax \rVert$

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you need more help!